# NavigableMap.firstKey throwing unwanted NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

From Javadocs of [`NavigableMap.firstKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#firstEntry()):

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the least key in this map, or `null` if the map is empty.

However, when I run the following program I am getting `NoSuchElementException`:

```java
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        NavigableMap<Object, Object> map = new TreeMap<>();
        Object obj = map.firstKey();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am missing something here. Why it is behaving like this?

Comment: According to the [JavaDocs `NavigableMap#firstKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#firstKey--) it *"Throws: NoSuchElementException - if this map is empty"*

Comment: @Joker - It doesn't say that for firstKey.

Comment: gotta learn to read javadocs

Comment: @MadProgrammer--You are checking sorted Map.

Comment: @ScaryWombat- Kindly check the link in my question its a java doc

Comment: The Javadoc you linked in your question is to `firstEntry()` but you are using `firstKey()`. The `firstKey()` Javadoc is inherited from `SortedMap` - it says that in the NavigableMap doc. The `firstKey()` method can't return null because null is a valid key. You wouldn't then be able to differentiate a null key from an empty map.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible/typo since the question asks about `firstKey` but links to `firstEntry` (despite the link being labeled as `firstKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `firstKey()` function's documentation states:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the first (lowest) key currently in this map.
>  *
>  * @return the first (lowest) key currently in this map
>  * @throws NoSuchElementException if this map is empty
>  */
> K firstKey();
> ```

So In your case the map is empty and therefore the exception

---

If you look at `TreeMap`'s implementation for the method then you see:

```
/**
 * @throws NoSuchElementException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public K firstKey() {
    return key(getFirstEntry());
}
```

The `getFirstEntry` returns `null` in case of an empty set and then the `key` method:

```
/**
 * Returns the key corresponding to the specified Entry.
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if the Entry is null
 */
static <K> K key(Entry<K,?> e) {
    if (e==null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return e.key;
}
```

Because the object itself is `TreeMap` and not `NavigableMap` you need to check the derived's implementation and documentation, even if the reference is to the base

Comment: Please check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#firstEntry()

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Gilad Green, the firstKey API is behaving as per documentation.

But I think you are probably looking for below method -

```
firstEntry()
Returns a key-value mapping associated with the least key in this map, or null if the map is empty.
```

This will give you Map.Entry object. And in your case it would return null as the map does not have any entry yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
returns null if there is no key
```

That is for value with key. But you are asking key itself.

[K firstKey()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#firstKey())

> Returns:
>       the first (lowest) key currently in this map
>
> Throws:
>       NoSuchElementException - if this map is empty